# Is each else a good place to put a loading image?

Tags: javascript, meteor

```
{{#each posts}}
    {{> post}}
{{else}}
    loader.gif
{{\each}}
```

I found about `else` in `each` accidentally and it seems it does its job quite good (at least on my localhost). What I want is to show a loader when meteor is still retrieving `posts` from the database. Does it do this job? What are the caveats of `else` in `each`?

Comment: "it seems it does its job quite good" ... "Does it do this job?" I don't get it :/

Comment: Never heard of `#each...else` block but if it works, putting a loading spinner in the `else` part is a good design pattern IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

## First, To answer your question...

Yes, it will work very well for exactly what you are trying to do.

## Else is a special block helper

From an unofficial source of documentation for Handlebars, from which spacebars/blaze/future stuff draws it's inspiration.

> `{{else}}` ... can be used with *any block helper* to represent what should be output if the given expression evaluates to a falsy value.

So, really, it doesn't matter **which** block helper you choose, whether you're using `#if`, `#each`, `#with`, etc...  The behavior is essentially the same.

That is, if your parameter, in this case `posts`, evaluates to a [falsy value](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/), the block thereafter will be evaluated instead.

## Those caveats...

There aren't really any caveats, but a tricky thing about falsy values is that empty arrays are actually truthy.  So, given your example, if `posts` **is defined**, but *empty*, it will still evaluate the first block, leaving you with an empty output.  This, for you, is ideal, since you want to display a loading block before it is defined.  However, I could easily see someone resolving to do the following:

```
{{#each posts}}
    {{content}}
{{else}}
    There are no posts today.
{{/each}}
```

Your empty `posts` array would evaluate to `true`, and you would never see the lack of posts message.  However, since `0` evaluates to false, you could wrap the block in an `#if` helper:

```
{{#if posts.length}}
    {{#each posts}}
        {{content}}
    {{else}}
        {{>spinner}}
    {{/each}}
{{else}}
    Sorry, there are no posts today.
{{/if}}
```

Source:
http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/handlebars-js-part-2-partials-and-helpers

Comment: -1 this answer might be correct for Handlebars, but in Spacebars the `{{else}}` still appears when the object is empty but truthy (for both lists and cursors). See this meteorpad: http://meteorpad.com/pad/SiG6XCujLb92F6NLG

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a good idea.

The `{{else}}` in an `{{#each cursor}}` block helper appears when the `cursor` is empty. You want to display the loading spinner when the subscription behind that cursor is not yet ready. These are not the same, in at least two situations:

1. There aren't actually any posts in the cursor. For example, the user searched for some posts and no posts matched the search, or the app just went live, and there aren't any posts at all. In this case, the user will see the loading spinner forever, and will assume your app is broken.

It is a good idea to put some message in the `{{else}}` though, so the user doesn't get confused by an empty list:

```html
{{#each posts}}
  {{> post}}
{{else}}
  There are no posts.
{{/each}}
```

2. The client has received some of the posts from the server, but not all of them. You want to display the spinner until all the posts have arrived, but with the `{{else}}` implementation, the spinner will disappear as soon as one post arrives. As the rest of the posts arrive, you'll see them appear as they arrive, which can be jarring. It's likely you won't see this happen in development due to low-latency, but in production, it's more likely.

The correct way is to use the subscription handle's reactive `ready` method:

```html
{{#if postsReady}}
  {{#each posts}}
    {{> post}}
  {{else}}
    There are no posts.
  {{/each}}
{{else}}
  loader.gif
{{/if}}
```

```js
// Somewhere in your code, something like this:
var postsSubscription = Meteor.subscribe(/* ... */);

// Top level:
Template.posts.helpers({
  postsReady: function() { return postsSubscription.ready(); },
  posts: function() { return Posts.find(); }
});
```

You should also consider using [iron:router](https://atmospherejs.com/iron/router), which has a great way to handle waiting on subscriptions using `waitOn`.

(If you've never seen `Meteor.subscribe` before, you're probably using `autopublish`, which is not suitable for real apps. Check out the Meteor docs on [publish and subscribe](http://docs.meteor.com/#publishandsubscribe).)